# custom cart price rule type in magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.1

In Magento 1.x and 2.0.x, used the event `adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform` to add custom cart price rule type.

But, from 2.1.0 onwards it is not working. Can anybody help on how to integrate custom rule types in cart price rule?

The code for the observer code in 2.0.0 is as below and it was working.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $actionsSelect = $observer->getForm()->getElement('simple_action');
    if ($actionsSelect) {

        $values = $actionsSelect->getValues();
        $values[] = array(
            'value' => 'my_promotions_percent',
            'label' => __('Reset price to percentage of actual price'),
        );
        $values[] = array(
            'value' => 'my_promotions_fixed',
            'label' => __('Reset price to new fixed price'),
        );

        $actionsSelect->setValues($values);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I am also facing the same issue in Magento2.1.0

Comment: Sorry, no. I have not checked it after that. Will check it when current work is finished and update here.

Answer (score 1):

This event `adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform` also used into Magento 2 so please make sure `events.xml` is proper.

You can also refer [link "How to handle events"](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/137)

Comment: yeah there is event, but i am not able to add it via the old code which i used for 2.0.0. There is some change in the form, not able to get it out.